# Appending list sometimes give 'IndexError: list index out of range' error and results in not as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, cluster-analysis

So i'm still new to programming and trying to implement an initialization method for a clustering problem using python-2.7.
The steps are:

1. Pick a random data from dataset as first centroid
2. While number of data in centroid < n_klas : Calculate the data distance to the data in centroids
3. Calculate the probability of all datas to their closest centroid using formula

   P(x) = D(x)**2 / sum(D(x)**2), in which D(x) is euclidean distance from data[x] to the closest centroid
4. Pick Data with highest P(x), then loop back to no.2.

But when i try to appending data sometimes i got this error 'IndexError: list index out of range' and sometimes the code works but only give 2 different centroid and the 3rd to n centroid give the same values as the 2nd centroid.

Where did i do wrong?

(Edit: i edited the steps to doi it because i was wrong)

```
def pickcentroid(df):
    x = df.values.tolist()
    n_klas = 3
 #   random.seed(2)
    idx_pusat_pertama = random.randint(0, len(df))
    centroid = []
    centroid_idx = []
    centroid.append(x[idx_pusat_pertama])
    centroid_idx.append(idx_pusat_pertama)
    prob_data = []
    while len(centroid) < n_klas:
        ac_mindist = 0
        for i in x:
            dist_ke_c = []
            for c in centroid:
                dist_ke_c.append(dist(i,c))
            ac_mindist += min(dist_ke_c)**2
        for idx in range(len(df)) : 
            if idx not in centroid_idx:
                dist_ke_c2 = []
                mindist_per_data = 0
                for c in centroid:
                    dist_ke_c2.append(dist(x[idx],c))
                mindist_per_data = min(dist_ke_c2)**2
                prob_data.append(mindist_per_data/ac_mindist)
            else:
                prob_data.append(0)
        new_cen_idx = prob_data.index(max(prob_data))
        centroid_idx.append(new_cen_idx)
        centroid.append(x[new_cen_idx])

    print(centroid)
    return centroid

def dist(x,y):
    r = np.array(x) - np.array(y)
    distance = np.linalg.norm(r)
#    print(distance)
    return distance


c = pickcentroid(df)
```

And the data looks like this:

```
-0.19864726098025476,-0.2174575876560727
-0.19427576174137176,-0.2658220115362011
0.24385376109048476,0.1555938625346895
-0.23636704446757748,0.14005058641250595
0.37563103051045826,0.33204816285389527
-0.13210748354848134,-0.0019122205360639893
-0.17120654390561796,0.04231258139538708
0.2865229979171536,0.34175192153482764
-0.328896319205639,-0.22737124434792602
0.03115098005450885,0.17089336362457433
```

Thankyou very much for your kind help

Answer (score 2):

The `randint(a, b)` returns random integers from `a` to `b`, *including* `b`. So, when you use `randint(0, len(x))`, you might get the value `len(x)` as output, which is out of range when used as index.

For your use case, you could probably use `random_value = random.choice(x)` instead.

Comment: so i've tried to change the value of b into the index of last data, so that problem should be solved but i still got the same error. It says got something to do with the  centroid.append(x[new_cen_idx])

Comment: @Elenora: you list might be empty, so *any* index value will be wrong

Comment: Sorry if this is so basic but which list might be empty? the '(x[new_cen_idx])'? but shouldnt that list can't be empty because it contains the whole dataset and i only tried to append the value of data with index from '[new_cen_index]' into the centroid list.

Comment: @Elenora: the `x` list. The only possible reason for your error is that `idx_pusat_pertama` refers to a position that `x` doesn't have. Assuming, of course, that `x` is a regular list.

Comment: Yes apparently whenever it returns an error  the 'idx_pusat_pertama' always return a same value of interger which is indeed outside of the range. In my case it always return 35 eventhough imy data is only 20. And if i added more data it'll eventually get the same error with different value of interger. I still couldn't understand why it happened though..